# Grails 3 - Domain not allowing Map constructors when moved to Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a number of domain classes that I've moved into a plugin as a Multi-Project Build. For some reason, they're no longer accepting Map constructors. For instance, before I could call:

```
def instance = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
```

But after I moved the domain classes into a plugin, I get the following error:

```
Error on startup: Could not find matching constructor for: com.testcompany.UserRole(java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

Is there something I need to do to re-enable domain classes to automatically accept named parameters in the plugin?

I'm using Grails 3.2.3.

Comment: map constructor should work properly. Can you show full stack trace, and config files?

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now but can get the stack trace tomorrow. I didn't modify any config files, although I did make the plugin using the plugin profile instead of the default web profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map constructors are added by `grails-plugin-controllers` as they weave the data binding logic into the constructors so you would need to add that dependency to the plugin, but only if you plan to use the domain classes exclusively in a web environment.

Otherwise you can always use `bindData(instance, [user: user, role: role])`

Comment: While I'm accepting your answer, I decided to just remake the plugin as the default web profile, and I transferred all the code to that. If I'm losing the benefits from the plugin profile over the web profile, I might as well go all the way with the web profile.